# Jmeter - JSON Extractor - issue with extracting the exact decimal value

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

I'm writing a test to assert that all amount values in a json contain 2 digits after the decimal point.
The JSON Extractor appears to ignore zero when reading the decimal values from the Json. So for example 8.50 will be 8.5 and consequently exact assertions are failing.

**Sample Json** that I added to the Dummy Sampler

```
{
    "shop": {
        "book": [
            {
                "author": "Author 1",
                "title": "Title 1",
                "price": 8.50
            },
        ],
        }
    },
}
```

My response assertion for price is set to 8.50

[Assertion result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5y9g.png)

In the results I get a failure as it indicates 8.5 was extracted rather than 8.50

Is there any steps needed to force the extractor to read the value exactly as it appears in the json?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's JSON Assertion relies on [JayWay JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/) and this underlying library has a bug inside.

You might want to [report this issue at their GitHub](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues) and if/once it will be resolved - [create an enhancement request for JMeter](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_severity=Enhancement&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&cmdtype=doit&order=Bug%20Number&product=JMeter) to use this newer better library.

In the meantime you can use [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as the workaround, the relevant Groovy code would be:

```
def expectedPrice = 8.50

def actualPrice = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).shop.book[0].price

if (expectedPrice != actualPrice) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Price mismatch, expected: ' +  expectedPrice + ', got: ' + actualPrice)
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)

Comment: @TestMcc There's existing bug https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/542